# Is Refocus an action in 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, actions

Is Refocus still an action in D&D 3.5? In original 3e, it was a full-round action which reset your initiative as though you had rolled a natural 20. However, I can't find that rule on d20srd.com. (I am only interested in the current state of the 3.5 rules, not in whether those rules are fair or good.)

If so, why doesn't it appear in the SRD? If not, is there any authoritative indication (e.g. author interviews) for why it was removed?

Comment: This is two questions, one which is easily answerable (*is this still part of 3.5?*), and another which is almost impossible to answer (*why isn’t it on the SRD?* or *why not?* depending on the previous answer). In its current state, you will almost-certainly never get a complete answer. I suggest asking only the portion of the question that is likely to actually be answered.

Comment: I considered that carefully, and wasn't sure what the best approach was. Because the second question only makes sense in the context of the first, I asked together. Very willing to take advice on asking a better question though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not part of 3.5. I am not aware of any commentary on why this is so.

However, it’s notable that the Delay action effectively covers what Refocus used to do. By delaying to the end of *this* round, you go before anyone else goes *next* round. And which round you are actually in (*this* or *next*) is irrelevant in 3.5.

Comment: Delay as a refocus replacement discussed at length in an [*EN World* thread](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?158235-Refocus-disappeared-in-3-5).

Comment: Delay didn't loop into the next round in 3.0. @HeyICanChan's link clarified it for me.

Comment: @fectin AEG both in its Oriental Adventures line and its d20 System RPG *Spycraft* make liberal use of numeric initiative  (the latter more than the former), but *D&D 3E* usually didn't, so once the DM determined who went after whom, the real *numbers* behind initiative didn't matter to most *D&D* players; eliminating refocus in favor of expanding delat meant simplifying a little a complex process… y'know, unless your system actually *used* those numbers. Crafty Games's *Spycraft 2.0*, for example, continues using numeric initiative despite being (squint hard, tilt your head) *3.5* compliant.

Comment: It functions slightly differently (e.g. if you have a +0 mod, you could never go between initiatives 25 and 23 before), but yes. I've been playing 3.0 the past few weeks, and I'm just rusty enough that obscure changes like this can catch me.